# Grid view and Details Page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, master-detail

I have a page which has job search , up on job search the results are bound to the gridview. The Gridview has hyperlink
Column, when user clicks on the column it goes to another page which displays the complete details of the job

My requirement is I have to add prev and next to the page which shows the details of the job

for example

go to http://forums.asp.net/15.aspx/1?Getting+Started
and click on any row and it takes to the topic and also the page has "next thread" and "prev thread" option

Answer (score 0):

You may save search results in Session and pass selected item index in query string to details page. On the details page you just get item by index from already saved search results and use it for show details info.